# How to Use python3 loop to read file N lines and POST to server

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm some trouble in Use python3 loop to read file N lines and POST to the server.
my file urls.txt like this(Tens of thousands of lines):

```
https://www.xxxx.com/html/1.html 
https://www.xxxx.com/html/2.html 
https://www.xxxx.com/html/3.html 
https://www.xxxx.com/html/4.html 
https://www.xxxx.com/html/5.html 
https://www.xxxx.com/html/6.html 
https://www.xxxx.com/html/7.html 
https://www.xxxx.com/html/8.html
```

I want to post them to a server which limited 2000 lines one time, so I want to find some ways to solve this problem, my code as follow:

```
filename = 'urls.txt'

max_lines = 2000
url_list = []
with open(filename,'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    while True:
        next_n_lines = list(islice(f,max_lines))
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        url_list = [line.strip() for line in next_n_lines if line.strip() != '']
        data = '\n'.join(url_list)
        domain = 'www.xxxx.com'
        token = 'xsdssdsddsdsd'
        url = 'http://post.xxxx.com/urls?domain=%s&token=%s' % (
            domain, token)
        headers = {
            'Host': 'post.xxxx.com',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'
        }
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=5)
        data = r.json()
        print(data)
```

But,when i run my code it only posted the first 2000 lines urls to the srever, what's wrong whith my code ,and could you give me some suggestion or other ways ?
thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest splitting the file reading and the actual HTTP requests. Something like

```
# read all the lines
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# iterate over each chunk
max_lines = 2000
for i in range(0, len(lines), max_lines):
    chunk = lines[i:i + max_lines]
    assert len(chunk) <= max_lines

    # ... and then continue with the HTTP request
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give you a reply.

Answer (score 1):

From what i could see, you only take the first 2000 lines from the file. Consider this:

```
filename = 'urls.txt'

max_lines = 2000
start_index = 0;
url_list = []
with open(filename,'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    while True:
        next_n_lines = list(islice(f, start_index, start_index + max_lines))
        start_index = start_index + max_lines
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        url_list = [line.strip() for line in next_n_lines if line.strip() != '']
        data = '\n'.join(url_list)
        domain = 'www.xxxx.com'
        token = 'xsdssdsddsdsd'
        url = 'http://post.xxxx.com/urls?domain=%s&token=%s' % (
            domain, token)
        headers = {
            'Host': 'post.xxxx.com',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'
        }
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=5)
        data = r.json()
        print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, bro, I will answer you after I tried it.

Comment: hey,bro thanks a lot for you helping me,but this code run with some troubles which only posted a part of these urls...